# Communication between java spring server and python applications

Tags: java, python, spring

I designed my java spring application to run a couple of python programs on same server and communicate with them. I run them with ProcessBuilder and communicate via InputStream/OutputStream. 
Now I want to achieve that when I restart or shut down my java application, python apps didnt close. I can't get Process object by PID. With ProcessHandler object  I can't get input/output streams. It seems that i should use some other mechanism of IPC. So the questions are:

1. How can I run external applications from java so they wouldn't close when java app restarts?
2. How can I achieve communication between java and python applications without having Process object?

Thanks in advance, sorry for poor language :)

Answer (score 0):

I give some suggestion on our project experience:

1. In single server, use docker-compose to run/stop app no matter using java or python. In multi-server，they will be deployed in Istio.
2. use Restful protocol to communicate between them.

Comment: Thank you! There is a lot to think about. Now reading kubernetes docs, seems to be also a decision for the first question. Now as I understood network communication is the only option for java and python apps to interact